# How to make React check the user input from the first character?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, web, state

React App. Auth form. On user input I'm checking if the user is writing correct stuff(email for email and latin chars + digits for password)

The problem is, that it shows result in the browser not at the moment of typing, but one character later.
Examples:

1. Should check from the first char, but doesn't:
   [Starting to enter smth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJgkH.jpg)
2. Should already show the message, that all is ok, but doesn't. Only shows after + one extra symbol typed:
   [Finishing typing email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sYIe.jpg)
   [Added a space and it worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7ofD.jpg)

The input is as follows:

```
                        <input
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='Email'
                        name='login'
                        required
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
```

The handler (the login part, for password the same):

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        field: event.target.name,
    });
    if (this.state.field === 'login') {
        this.setState({
            loginValue: event.target.value,
        });
        const result = this.checkLogin(this.state.loginValue);
        if (result == true) {
            this.setState({loginErrorMessage: "Email true", loginValid: true})
        } else {
            this.setState({loginErrorMessage: result.message.toString(), loginValid: false})
        }
    }
}
```

The checking fuction:

```
    checkLogin(value) {
    try {
        if (value.match(/^[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}$/) == null) {
            throw new Error("Value must be email");
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    } catch (myError) {
        return myError
    }
}
```

I'm new to state managing in general and to React in particular. I guess I'm changing state somewhere in the wrong place. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target.value` instead of `this.state.loginValue` as you saves it on the same function, The way react setState works is - it finishes the function first before it reflects the state, so if you have additional logic after that on the same function it will still use the old (current) value.

Just replace these lines with:

```
 if (event.target.name === 'login') {
```

and

```
 const result = this.checkLogin(event.target.value);
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped starting cheking from the first character. But in the end of input it still doesn't show good result. But it turned me into the right direction and I combined your suggestion with axtck's about promises. So it worked together in the end.

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` is asynchronous, meaning that if you try to use the value immediately after setting the state, it will not have updated yet. Try using the `checkLogin()` function in the callback of `setState()`.

```js
this.setState({
  loginValue: event.target.value,
}, () => {
  const result = this.checkLogin(this.state.loginValue);
  if (result == true) {
    this.setState({
      loginErrorMessage: "Email true",
      loginValid: true
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      loginErrorMessage: result.message.toString(),
      loginValid: false
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped showing the OK message right when the input becomes correct.. But it still doesn't check the first character I input. . I combined your suggestion about promises with I am L's answer and it helped.